# CollapsingToolbarLayout set animation threshold?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, androiddesignsupport

In my application when I start scrolling the layout, the CollapsingToolbarLayout starts almost immediately changing the background to the scrim color I set.

[image: Before scrolling]
[image: After start scrolling]

Is there a way to set the value at which the CollapsingToolbar starts to change the background?

This is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="eu.ericnisoli.ambrosettiap.activities.MeetingActivity"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameLayout_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout_info">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView_bg"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/login_bg"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/detail_meeting_gradient" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingStart="16dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="80dp"
                        android:paddingTop="16dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_meeting"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="@string/meeting"
                            android:textColor="@color/text_grey_1"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_14"
                            android:textAllCaps="true"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
                            android:text="New Text"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/frameLayout_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/grey_2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingTop="32dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="32dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:gravity="center">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/pin_small_icon"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView_place"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_black_1"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView_address"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_black_1"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:paddingTop="32dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="32dp">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:gravity="center">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:src="@drawable/cal_small_icon"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView_date"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_black_1"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/textView_time"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:textColor="@color/text_black_1"/>
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@string/event_caps"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/grey_2"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/text_black_1"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_black_1"
                style="@style/DetailTab"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/frameLayout_title"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

With version 26.1 or newer, you can use the [`scrimVisibleHeightTrigger`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout#setscrimvisibleheighttrigger) attribute to set the height threshold when to show the scrim overlay.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:scrimVisibleHeightTrigger="80dp"
    ...>
```

> Set the amount of visible height in pixels used to define when to trigger a scrim visibility change.
>
> If the visible height of this view is less than the given value, the scrims will be made visible, otherwise they are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

#### Dry

After looking into [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)'s implementation, you may see, that content scrim is appearing when `CollapsingToolbarLayout` height gets lower than its `minimum height x 2 + "status bar height"`:

```
if (mContentScrim != null || mStatusBarScrim != null) {
    setScrimsShown(getHeight() + verticalOffset < getScrimTriggerOffset() + insetTop);
}
```

and here is `getScrimTriggerOffset` implementation:

```
final int getScrimTriggerOffset() {
    return 2 * ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(this);
}
```

Unfortunately setting `minHeight` property won't work, because this piece of code will overwrite it during `onLayout`:

```
if (mToolbarDirectChild == null || mToolbarDirectChild == this) {
    setMinimumHeight(getHeightWithMargins(mToolbar));
} else {
    setMinimumHeight(getHeightWithMargins(mToolbarDirectChild));
}
```

#### Solution

Extend `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and after `onLayout` call `setMinimumHeight`. You may also use the following implementation with `setContentScrimHeight` method:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class MyCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {

    private int contentScrimHeight;

    public MyCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        super.setMinimumHeight(contentScrimHeight);
    }

    public int getContentScrimHeight() {
        return contentScrimHeight;
    }

    public void setContentScrimHeight(int contentScrimHeight) {
        this.contentScrimHeight = contentScrimHeight;
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sucks that we have to edit the actual minHeight for this to work. In my case, I wanted to have a different minHeight, and just edit the point where the Scrim animation would start. This would be easily achievable by just overreding the method getScrimTriggerOffset, but Google Engineers decided to make it final for some reason...

Answer (score -1):

Use `setParallaxMultiplier(float)` on view's layout parameters with id `relativeLayout_title`.

`setParallaxMultiplier` changes the threshold at which parallax animation starts triggering. By default it triggers at half the parent height, equivalent of setting the value of 0.5f.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.html#setParallaxMultiplier(float))